# Вывод данных в формате json

Tags: java, json

Делаю простой калькулятор как вывести в формате json?

```
   int rez=0;
```

Выводит JSON=10
Должно быть

```
{
"rez":10
}
```

Comment: не должно быть. Переменная `rez` у вас не объект с атрибутом `rez`, а значит выводит всё верно. Число как число

Comment: @ArchDemon как правильно сделать? Если передавать параметры, то можно их корректно обработать. Тут же результат формируется после обработки

Comment: Как минимум нужно создать класс и добавить в него атрибут `rez`. Я не работал с Gson, только jackson, так что не подскажу что нужно делать дальше

Answer (score 1):

## Вариант №1

Создаем класс, описывающий нужную структуру

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int rez;

    public SomeClass() {

    }

    public SomeClass(int rez) {
        this.rez = rez;
    }

    public int getRez() {
        return rez;
    }

    public void setRez(int rez) {
        this.rez = rez;
    }
}
```

Потом создаем объект и сериализуем

```java
SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass(10);
String jsonString = gson.toJson(someObject);
pw.print(jsonString);
```

## Вариант №2

Просто пихаем все в `Map` и сериализуем его

```java
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("rez", 1);
String jsonString = gson.toJson(map);
pw.print(jsonString);
```

Данный вариант подойдёт если мы не собираемся повторно использовать подобные структуры(особенно если их много)